# How to distinguish between anonymous vm_area_struct and file-mapped vm_area_struct?

Tags: linux-kernel, mmu

How can I detect that area represented by structure **vm_area_struct** was mapped as ANONYMOUS? I use `!vma->vma_file && vma->anon_vma`, but it doesn't work.

Comment: How do you identify that it doesn't work?

Comment: The space is displayed as anon by using pmap pid,but its vma_file is not NULL and points to a valid file.

Answer (score 0):

It's my fault.I add code to vma_link to monitor the allocation of process vitural address space.The area is mapped with a file but unmapped almost immediately.So,when use pmap to see the space maps,this area doesn't corresponds to a file.